# Creating new copies of slides with data from google sheets without loosing original template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides-api

I have made a script that replaces placeholder text in google slides with information from google sheet.
However once I have run the script once my slides template is overwritten with the injected information.

How to I preserve my original template while generating new copies of my slides?

I use the "SpreadsheetApp.openById" to get the spreadsheet, and I am also able to save a copy of the new file using "DriveApp.getFileById" and "makeCopy()". However my original template is still overwritten and all my placeholder tags {{tag}} are lost.

I use this function for replacing elements in the google slide:

```
values.forEach(function(row){
var templatevariable= row[0];
var templatevalue= row[1]
Presentation.replaceAllText(templatevariable,templatevalue);  
})
```

Comment: you should use duplicate() to copy your slide and made change on the duplicated one. Then you will not lose your original template. Is that what you asking for?   If you want the template and the final file separated. Using SlideApp open to call the template one.

Comment: @liquidkat Basically I have two original files:
- a master spread sheet with data
- a master slides template
If I duplicate the slides template I would need some kind of way to retrieve it and make the changes on the copy instead of the original. I guess that would not be possible to do with the 'openbyId' method, since it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a duplicate and then work on the duplicate.

```
var copiedFile = createCopyUsingDriveApp()

values.forEach(function(row){
  var templatevariable= row[0];
  var templatevalue= row[1]
  copiedField.replaceAllText(templatevariable,templatevalue);  
})


function createCopyUsingDriveApp() {
 // The Id of the presentation to copy
 var templateId = "<SLIDES_ID>";

 // Create a copy of the presentation using DriveApp
 var template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
 var fileName = template.getName();
 var copy = template.makeCopy();
 return copy.setName("Copy of " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: I am still learning, but just to understand: How do I ensure that the changes I make are in the copied version of the slide? Which method should I use to retrieve this? 
I don't have the id and url before the copy is created?

Comment: within the function `createdCopyUsingDriveApp`in the line where you call `template.makeCopy()`, a copy of the file is created and it is returned. In the next live `copy.setName()`, you are setting the name of the copy and returning the copy.  So no need for the id of copy, because you have the copy object, which you are modifying in your `forEach` function. If you want the id or url of the copy, just do `copiedFile.getUrl()` or `copiedFile.getId()`.